# yarn start - command "start" not found

Tags: json, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

`yarn start` leads to an error saying command "start" not found. In my package.json file there is no script's tag, could that be the issue. Please suggest a fix.

I am trying to install react, the commands being:

```
npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2
create-react-app confusion
yarn start
```

cmd error:
[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leTvP.png)

package.json:

```
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to run yarn first then yarn start.

Comment: I tried doing that but didn't work.

Comment: I think this is something to do with yarn installation itself. Are you using linux? If so then try to install global package with ‘sudo’ and replicate my advice above.

Comment: no, I am using windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` // uninstall the old create-react-app version (in your case, v1.5.2) to make sure npx uses the latest version in Step 2
2. `npx create-react-app my-react-app-name` // npx installs the latest version of create-react-app without requiring a global install. it is included with npm, so no need to install it. if you wish, replace *my-react-app-name* with whatever you want your project to be called
3. `cd my-react-app-name`
4. `yarn start`